# How can I get five Mushroom spores when the whole planet has only two mushrooms?

Tags: eco

I've started a game with a friend of mine. Very early in the game, we stumbled upon the problem, that the whole planet only has two Criminimushrooms (the plant itself, not the area). From one of them, I got a spore, but in order to create the farming skill book, I need four more. Is it possible to get more spores out of this one? I'm afraid to waste it when I implant in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to increase the yield gained from harvest, with the Wetlands Wanderer skill, from Gathering specialty ([source](https://eco.gamepedia.com/Wetlands_Wanderer)):

> Wetlands Wanderer is a skill in the Gathering specialty. It requires
>   Forest Forager Level 1 to unlock.
>
> It increases yield gained from the following plant resources: Amanita
>   Mushroom Spores, Amanita Mushrooms, Crimini Mushroom Spores, Crimini
>   Mushrooms, Rice.

Then your problem seems to be a known one, as this player states on [this steam community post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/382310/discussions/4/1699416432420626984/):

> I had the same issue. Think it's a known bug they really dont care
>   about, you know, being more or less game breaking.

This user finally had to cheat the game with a command in order to get his spores.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is what I was afraid of. But to be honest, when the game has a bad balancing like this, I don't feel bad about using the console to create the spores.